# Sous-vide short ribs including marinade

Tags: meat, sous-vide, barbecue

I plan to make sous-vide [Korean-style short ribs](https://twokooksinthekitchen.com/korean-beef-short-ribs-sous-vide/) this weekend, but I don't have a vacuum machine or easy access to decent ziplocs. I usually ask my butcher to vacuum the meat, including spices or marinade.

In this case, however, the recipe calls for marinating for 24 hours, then *removing* the marinade, and proceeding to sous-vide the ribs for 24 hours.

Would *not* removing the marinade hurt the result? Because if not, I'll just have my butcher vacuum seal the ribs including the marinade, pop in the fridge for a day, then in the water bath for an additional day, before finishing on the grill.

Answer (score 2):

If the marinade is very salty or strong in some other way, thus if you do not remove it you may end up with extra salty or strong flavors. In general, cooking sous-vide with marinades will not "hurt" the result, many sous-vide recipes include seasonings and marinades.

As you and your butcher seem friendly, perhaps you can collaborate on a few experiments to find what preparations you enjoy most:

1. Perform a simple side-by-side experiment: Select to differ preparations by your butcher (marinade and no marinade) and cook them the same way to see which you prefer.
2. If you wish to attempt to remove the marinade before cooking sous-vide, ask you butcher to leave the bag long on one side so that you can cut off just the seal, then squeeze the marinade out of the bag and then just clip the open end of the bag to the side of your sous-vide container during the cook.
3. If you butcher has any pre-marinated meats, perhaps they can remove the marinades before vacuum-sealing.

Good luck, have fun, and enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for your advice!